# Populating a Dropdown List with the next two business weeks c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, while-loop

I am trying to create a dropdown list in a C# asp.net webform that populates with mon-sat for this week and the next to be used in an appointment scheduling form.

```
public void Datetime_Fill()
{
    DateTime Date = DateTime.Now;
    int sunday_count = 0;

    while(sunday_count < 2)
    {
        if (Date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("The day of the week for {0:d} is {1}.", Date, Date.DayOfWeek);
            ddl_Appt_Date.Items.Add(new ListItem(Date.DayOfWeek.ToString()));
            Date.AddDays(1);
        }
        else
        {
            Date.AddDays(1);
            sunday_count++;
        }
    }
}
```

I have this execute on page load and whenever I load it my webpage does not display at all and the browser sits there loading. I am assuming that Date.DayOfWeek never equals DayOfWeek.Sunday and so it never leaves the while loop. I put the Console.WriteLine in there just for troubleshooting but still nothing displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to do

`Date = Date.AddDays(1);`

as `Date` is never being updated.

From [MSDN DateTime :](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx)

`DateTime.AddDays() returns a new DateTime that adds the specified number of days to the value of this instance.`

Comment: Wow I feel like an idiot, even had my boos come over and look at it and he didn't catch that ether. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be having a table on a database with all the dates to exclude. That way, you could also predict if there's a holiday during the week or something like that.

The way you're doing, you're only taking off Sunday. Is that what you really need?

Also, you should work with `value` and `text` on all Dropdownlists.

For example:

```
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("<text>", value));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the return value of the addDay function to update your date object and to reach sunday, so:

Date = Date.AddDays(1);